# How to override a timestamp field for unit test purposes?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unit-testing

```
class Record(ndb.Model):
    notes = ndb.TextProperty()
    last_updated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

Part of Unit Test setup:

```
record2 = Record()    
# trying to set the last_updated timestamp to a previous date
record2.last_updated = previous_date

record2.put()
#after saving it, the timestamp is back to today's date
```

Hence I can't emulate an old record for my unit testing.  How do I override that field without having to change the model?

Comment: From the docs  - `It is possible to override the value for a property with auto_now_add=True, but not for one with auto_now=True. The automatic value is not generated until the entity is written; that is, these options don't provide dynamic defaults. (These details differ from the old db API.)` you will probably have to fiddle with the model whilst setting up for the tests.

Comment: @TimHoffman why not having that as an answer instead of comment?

Comment: I often do this when I am not satisfied with it as an answer :-)

Comment: @TimHoffman but it actually answers the question.. it's not possible :)

Comment: Yeah I did further research and it seems impossible. I changed the model to plain `last_updated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required=True)` that forces me to set the field and I have changed all references to the code accordingly. That way I can at least unittest it. Tim, you can put it as an answer and I tick it off. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#Date_and_Time)

> It is possible to override the value for a property with `auto_now_add=True`, but not for one with `auto_now=True`. The automatic value is not generated until the entity is written; that is, these options don't provide dynamic defaults. (These details differ from the old db API.)